# Finding relations between cells in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

This is a really basic question:

- I have a pandas series named "Income" which consists of 300 numbers.
- I want to find a specific relationship between any consecutive five numbers over the whole Series, in a loop.
- In other words, I wanna find 5 numbers where the first number > second, second > third, third < fourth, fourth < fifth.

I have tried iterating through the Series but keep getting errors.

What is the simplest approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
(df>df.shift(-1)) & (df.shift(-1)>df.shift(-2)) & (df.shift(-2)<df.shift(-3)) & (df.shift(-3)<df.shift(-4))
```

Comment: The output of this will be a boolean series, where the True / False will next to the fifth and last number in the series (so when you see a True, that number and the four preceding numbers will give you your relationship).